# Problem when getting records from database with relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm having trouble relating photos to tags using an intermediate table.

In the example below, how can I select all photos that belong to tag 1 with an Eloquent relationship method in Laravel?

I have these tables:

```
-Photos Table

 |  id  |    name    | description |
    1     photo1.png      ....
    2     photo2.png      ....
    3     photo3.png      ....
```

```
-Tags Table

 |  id  |    name    |
    1      Aesthetic
    2        Dark
```

```
-Tags Relations

 | id | tag_id | photo_id |
   1      1         3
   2      1         2
   3      2         1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, you need to ensure that both Photos and Tags table have the relationship defined.

Under the Photos model you should have the following function:

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Tag::class,
        "photos_tags", // the name of the pivot table
        "photo_id",
        "tag_id"
    );
}
```

Under the Tags model you should have the following function:

```
public function photos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Photo::class,
        "tags_photos", // the name of the pivot table
        "tag_id",
        "photo_id"
    );
}
```

Now to access all the tags that are related to the Photo of id 1, you can call the following:

```
Photo::findOrFail(1)->tags()->get();
```

And the same you can do for a specific tag to get all it's photos.

```
Tag::findOrFail(1)->photos()->get();
```

Hope this will lead you to what you wish.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Much luck in further development!^^